# How to list and choose folders in batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I want to list all folders present in the workspace of the batch file and select one of them for further processing.

I got some codes for listing & selecting files in the directory ([How can i make a selectable list out of a file search in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748724/how-can-i-make-a-selectable-list-out-of-a-file-search-in-a-batch-script))

I need the same for directories. codes for selecting files is give below.

Regards,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

:
:: Read in files
for %%x in (*.sln) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)

:
echo.
echo Select one:
echo.

:
:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
)
echo.

:
:: Retrieve User input
set /p select=? 
echo.

:
:: Print out selected filename
echo You chose !choice[%select%]!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` has the parameter `/d` to process directories instead of files:

```
for /d %%x in (*) do ...
```

for more info see `for /?`